# How to convert a low-resolution image to a background-gradient in CSS?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have been digging around the OpenAI website in F12 and on their front page and I have been quite interested in the main background.

The image source links to a 3x2 image of pixels that appear on the front page of the website, in a blurred gradient form.

I've checked all of the associated CSS with the Chrome developer tools, and I can't find anything on how they did this. I have searched all over the internet as well, which only links to generating gradients with CSS.

How can you take a low-resolution image like this and make it into a gradient?

[image: picture of website]

Comment: If you want to use css you can checkout this [gradient templates](https://webgradients.com/)

Comment: this is not one gradient, but multiple stacked gradient and not linear

Comment: @TemaniAfif nope, it's an image as seen in the answer below

Comment: image or not, I am talking about the visual which is not a simple gradient but multiple non-linear gradient layers .

Comment: @TemaniAfif No, I read through the source HTML, all that is included referencing the background of that div is the code posted in an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The style for the background is this:

```
background-image: url(/assets/images/home-gradient.gif?v=b0ac160331);
background-size: 100% 100%;
```

ie. they just stretch that small image to cover the whole area.

Comment: Yes but that wouldn't explain the blur effect, I was already aware of this css

Comment: I have tested this out and you are right, the blur is a side effect of the stretching.